# Dynamically populate an InfoPath DropownList with managed code

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, infopath

I have an InfoPath form with custom C# code, and a Sharepoint list.  I have a dropdownlist in the InfoPath form that I want to populate with a certain field from the Sharepoint list (I want the InfoPath dropdownlist to contain this field's value from every item in the Sharepoint list.  I can successfully get the list of values I need from Sharepoint in my managed code, but I do not see how I can get these values into the dropdownlist (either bind to the list, or add each item in the list one by one).  I thought I could modify the XML of the dropdownlist to insert my items, but the XML only contains the first item in the dropdownlist:

```
 <my:RelatedRiskID xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2009-07-20T18:12:59">Option 1</my:RelatedRiskID>
```

I feel like this should be possible, but I can't find any resources on how to do it.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to populate your dropdown list with a SharePoint list then you need to

- create a data connection to the said SharePoint list
- in the dropdown list Data tab, get the data externally and select the said data connection

Comment: It is better to show how to do something than just state what must be done. Especially when the question is specifically about "how"